# How hibernate first level cache work with spring data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, caching, spring-data-jpa

I know how the hibernate first level cache works, but wondering how it works with JPA,
as working on Spring data JPA everything is managed.

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate first level case is part of the JPA implementation of Hibernate and therefore works with JPA just as without.
There is no difference.

Spring Data JPA is build on JPA and doesn't modify the the behaviour of the first level cache in any way.